# Maximum number of trials required to open a lock using permutations and combinations

Tags: permutations, combinations

Q) To open a lock we are required to enter a number between 60 and 460, and it is an odd number, also that
the numbers belong to the set: {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5}. What will be the maximum number of trials?

what i tried-

so, as the numbers should be from the set {0,1,2,3,4,5}, there will be no possible number from 60 to 100, as all of them contain {6,7,8,9}, now for 100 to 460, i calculated 72 numbers which satisfy the conditions, but the answer doesn't seem to match, 144 is supposed to be the correct answer, no solutions are given, is it something to do with maximum trials? Any help is appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first digit can be any of $1,2,3,4$.

The second digit can be any of $0,1,2,3,4,5$

The third digit can be any of $1,3,5$

That gives $4\cdot6\cdot3=72$ choices.

Your answer appears to be correct.

Comment: then the given answer must be incorrect, thx for your help! much appreciated